# Android enabled makes my button be hidden

Tags: android, android-layout

When I use this:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="@string/rate"
        android:enabled="false" />
```

so simple Button initiation then my Button is hidden, but when I set enabled to true then it appears. How to solve that as I need to set enabled to false?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable click event for button use -

```
android:enabled="false"
```

If you want to hide the view use -

```
android:visibility="gone"
```